# Need to filter products

Tags: magento-1.9, category, attributes, filter

For a own test.phtml I need a filter by Product Attribute and Category.
if the product is in category X and have custom-attribute x 
echo sku

what is the right code?

I found solutions for each (categoryfilter / attributefilter) but not a combination of both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$categoryId = X;
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)->getProductCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
                ->addFieldToFilter('x_attribute_name','Value');
```

Comment: Can I combine a filter with: echo $product->getSku(); ? Becouse i have different  customattribute. Like something like this $product->getSku()->addAttributeToFilter('my customattribute').

Comment: If you want to filter by different attributes, add them one after the other like: `->addFieldToFilter('x_attribute_name','Value') ->addFieldToFilter('x_attribute_name2','Value');` Or if you want with different sku : `->addAttributeToFilter( 'sku', array( 'in' => array( 'sku1', 'sku2', 'sku3' ) ) )`

Comment: Thanks for your response it help a lot. My situation is special. I have a picture with Positon Numbers (for a spare parts list). At first the category and the Picture position Nr. Exist. The SKU comes later. So I need something like that: if sku have posnr. x and is in category x put this sku in variable x. The atributes for this:  ->addAttributeToFilter('posnr',array( 'in' => array( 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'B1', 'B2'))); What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing fancy to do in your case.

Suppose your category id is 3 and the attribute to filter is weight having value 5.

To get products filtered by a particular category

```
<?php
$categoryId = 3;
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                    ->load($categoryId)
                    ->getProductCollection();
?>
```

and whenever you want to apply a filter for an attribute, you use:

```
$whateverproductcollection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute-code','condition');
```

So, combining both as per considered category and attribute values, below code can be used:

```
<?php
$categoryId = 3;
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                    ->load($categoryId)
                    ->getProductCollection();
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('weight',array('eq' => 5));
?>
```

When you print_r the response:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($collection->getData());
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

You can get the result as required.